# Excel- Delete rows if a cell in a particular column contains values found in another column

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want to delete all the rows if the value in Vendor column is found in another column. (lookupVendor Col in another sheet)

[image]

**`MainSheet`**

**`LookupColumn`**

```
VendorCol
google 
microsoft
apple
vendorA
VendorB
```

Here is what I have but it only delete for one value.
How can I make it use the entire LookupColumn and detete any rows that colc value is found in lookupColumn.
My simple VBA code handles one value at a time.(which is not efficient)

```
Sub Find_Vendor()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim what As String
    what = "Microsoft"
    Do
        Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Find(what)
        If rng Is Nothing Then
            Exit Do
        Else
            Rows(rng.Row).Delete
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Mainsheet: Contains 600,000 rows
LookupColumn contains 400 entries.
The existing code is super slow for the volume of data I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use AutoFilter():

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Find_Vendor()
    Dim filters As Variant
    With Sheets("LookupColumnSheet") ' change "LookupColumnSheet" to your actual sheet with lookup values name
        filters = Application.Transpose(.Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Value) ' collect "LookupColumnSheet" sheet column A values from row 1 down to last not empty row
    End With

    With Sheets("MainSheet") 'reference "MainSheet" sheet (change "MainSheet" to your actual "MainSheet" sheet name
        With .Range("C1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp)) ' reference referenced sheet column C cells from row 1 down to last not empty one
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=filters, Operator:=xlFilterValues ' filter referenced range with values from "LookupColumnSheet" sheet column A
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete ' if any filtered cells other than header then delete their entire row
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False ' remove filters
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I get a 400 error. Added an image. please see above. Runtime error-1004, Application=-defined or object defined error. I am using Excel 2016

Comment: It is modal pop window showing the error, doesn't say which line

Comment: When you hit the error, click “Debug” button and you’ll be brought to the offending line

Comment: The Mainsheet and the error is on this line :             If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete ' if any filtered cells other than header then delete their entire row
As soon as it reaches .Resize....

Comment: then "MainSheet" sheet layout is not as you show right after "MainSheet" (i.e. : "ColA ColB  ColC..), is it?

Comment: You are correct, I wanted to show a simple few col. Image is the correct layout.

Comment: then just adapt my code (which is built as per your "MainSheet" original layout) to match your actual "Vendor" column index

Comment: I did adjust but still the same. Changed the col to use G1 instead of C1 as shown in image. but no luck. Here is the modified code:
        With .Range("G1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp))

Comment: try typing in Immediate Window (CTRL-G to pop it out) `?.Range("G1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp)).Address ` and press return and see if the outcome fits your expectations

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169792/discussion-between-stryker-and-displayname).